# Heroku - Could not import settings (Django)

Tags: django, heroku

I've deleted the `settings.py` file and create a `settings` directory at the same level, And created three files. Here are these files.

- `settings/production.py`
- `settings/staging.py`
- `settings/__init__.py`

and put in the `init` file the following statements.

```
site_env = get_env_variable('SITE_ENV')
if site_env:
    if site_env == 'staging':
        from .staging import *
    elif site_env == 'production':
        from .production import *
```

But I am getting error `raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))`. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but Heroku may need a `settings.py` file. You can check conditions under that file and import which settings needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the `Procfile` and create a new `common.py` file in `settings` dir. Then I put the following contents in common.py. Now Both servers are running. Thanks :-)

```
site_env = get_env_variable('SITE_ENV')
if site_env:
    if site_env == 'staging':
        from .staging import *
    elif site_env == 'production':
        from .production import *
```

`Procfile` File ->

`web: python manage.py runserver --settings=myapp.settings.common 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`

Comment: WARNING: this should come with a great big one. Do not use the `runserver` command in a production setting like Heroku as it is a development server and not made for that, it will be highly insecure. Instead use `gunicorn` or equivalent as per the Heroku docs.